# how to use nature unique key with surrogate key?

Tags: mysql, database

I am designing my database with MySQL. I will use `surrogate key` for all my tables. But I also want to keep the `nature unique key` really unique.
For example in my `Customer` table, I have a `surrogate key` which is an auto-increment number. There is also a `customerUserName` field which should be **unique**.
*How can I enforce this to make sure each customerUserName field are different?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a unique key constraint to your customerUserName field.

It will be something like this

> ALTER TABLE Customer ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Customer_customerUserName UNIQUE (customerUserName)